# Filter only by having blank/empty string cells

Tags: openrefine

I want to investigate the rows for which a certain column is empty. I'll fill these cells based on values in other columns, but I want to identify which ones have not yet been done.

If I make a filter on that column, it doesn't do anything until I type something - but the thing I'm looking for is nothing...

I tried a few regexs, like `^$`, `^\s*$` and `^.{0}$`, but no rows are select for any of these filters.

Answer (score 10):

I found it: in the dropdown for the column you're interested in, roll over `Facets`, then choose `Customized facets` then the last option is `Facet by blank`.

You then get a facet pane over on the right with two choices: `false` and `true`. If you roll over `true` you can click `include` (similarly to other facets), which selects rows that are blank. Voila!

I found this in the "*6. Remove blank cells*" section of http://freeyourmetadata.org/cleanup/